Find the sum of a specific code in each tabs
I’m encountering an issue in my Google Sheets where I need to calculate the sum of values associated with a specific code, which appears in multiple tabs. Whenever the code changes, the total should also update automatically.
Sample Sheet Link
i tried this =QUERY({Table1!A:B; Table2!A:B; Table3!A:B}, "SELECT Col2 WHERE Col1 = 'abc'", 0).
but not working

Sum Multiple Specific Value from Multiple Sheets
You can use this alternative Formula based on the request that you post.
Table 3 Cell B2 will not add the value from Table 1 Cell B and Table 2 Cell B if the Table 1 and 2 Cell A doesn't have the value abc.
Formula
=SUM(
  ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN({FILTER(Table1!B:B, Table1!A:A = "abc"); FILTER(Table2!B:B, Table2!A:A = "abc")}))
)

Sample Output

Reference:
ArrayFormula
Flatten

could you please work on my sample sheet. it will be really hellpful

You formula almost correct except Table3!A:B. You have space after sheet name Table1 . Remove that space or add that space in formula also. Try
=QUERY({Table1!A:B;Table2!A:B},"SELECT sum(Col2) WHERE Col1 = 'abc' label sum(Col2) ''", 0)



could you please do that formula in that sample sheet
